# "Serializing CDT Project settings" -- Eclipse error

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I tried to configure Eclipse and got this errors. How i can solve this?

There is an error, when i try to launch Eclipse.

[image: Error1]

And this error, when i try to change Android project settings.

[image: Error2]

Comment: facing the same problem using cocos2d-x version 3.2

Comment: i got the same problem on "eclipse juno",NDK :- android-ndk-r9d ,cocos-2dx :- cocos2d-x-3.6 . any solution for the same..please let me know thank you !!

Comment: Refer to this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28873491/6320124) It worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was facing the same problem but this answer worked for me give it a try.

[Serializing CDT Project settings has encountered a null pointer exception exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28873491/6320124)

(from there:

> Eclipse had added an extra node to my .cproject file, making it three
>   in total. I removed this one, which was the one added by Eclipse and
>   also the last one in the file.

```
<cconfiguration id="0.1230402123.1377291156">
    <storageModule buildSystemId="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider" id="0.1230402123.1377291156" moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings" name="Debug">
        <externalSettings/>
        <extensions>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.VCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GmakeErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CWDLocator" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GCCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GASErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GLDErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
        </extensions>
    </storageModule>
    <storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.externalSettings"/>
</cconfiguration>
```

> After removing that and restarting Eclipse everything was working
>   again.

)