# Serializing CDT Project settings has encountered a

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

When I build my project I get this error.

```
Serializing CDT Project settings has encountered a problem (Null Pointer Exception)
```

I am using latest eclipse and trying to build cocos2d-x3.2 for Android.

Comment: post the code and highlight the line where the error occurs

Comment: I found the answer for it. Its some eclipse error

Comment: @GeoPaul Please post the solution as an answer then, so future users can also fix it when finding this question.

Comment: Facing same problem , please help

Comment: @Geo Paul  , please share the Solution.

Answer (score 8):

After spending a few hours trying to figure out the same error message this morning (along with a bunch of nondescript nullpointerexceptions from Eclipse) I compared the Eclipse project files with previous version and found that Eclipse had added an extra  node to my .cproject file, making it three in total. I removed this one, which was the one added by Eclipse and also the last one in the file.

```
    <cconfiguration id="0.1230402123.1377291156">
        <storageModule buildSystemId="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider" id="0.1230402123.1377291156" moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings" name="Debug">
            <externalSettings/>
            <extensions>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.VCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GmakeErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CWDLocator" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GCCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GASErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GLDErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            </extensions>
        </storageModule>
        <storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.externalSettings"/>
    </cconfiguration>
```

After removing that and restarting Eclipse everything was working again.

I hope this helps someone. I'm not sure whether this was unique or something that causes issues for others, but clearly the error points towards a CDT problem and therefore comparing the .cproject file to previous versions (or default ones) for changes is worth a shot.

Comment: Fixed it for me and also fixed other annoying goings on in Eclipse.
You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by deleting

> .cproject and 
>   .project

file and build project again and replace past other project .cproject now it work fine

Answer (score -1):

Someone said him replaced cdt plugin v8.1.2 to v8.1.0 can resolve this problem.

Comment: how to do that ... i m facing same problem   My CDT version is 8.1.2

Comment: i did that , not much help.  it still giving errors.