# Error in Eclipse when trying to export apk

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to export my game apk for publishing to the store, but then I get an error saying 'compilation issues', how do i fix this? I've tried everything, it still doesnt get fixed, and when i go to my project theres a red x over my project, i'm guessing this might be the error, please refer to the screenshot

http://postimg.org/image/osiir584t/

Comment: try to find what is the error. may be some library missing. just check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Steps :

1.Remove Automatic build selection

2.Clean your project

3.Build the project

4.Export the apk

Comment: doesn't work, just tried it, still says 'project has compilation errors', does it help to know that i changed the src from 'com.temple.iKnife' to 'com.quddus.biebernator'?

Comment: then please check that your menifest.xml file have the correct package name as updated com.quddus.biebernator. Because by default it would not update

Comment: is the manifest file the only file i need to change it in? because i did and it still gives me errors

Answer (score 0):

First fix your project's error then you can export it.

1. Fix your project code(Make sure that don't present any error) that gives compilation error.
2. Clean your project
3. Then export for publish your app..

Answer (score 0):

Well, unsurprisingly this means the compiler runs into problems when compiling the release apk. These errors should appear in either the 'Problems' view or one of the consoles (you may need to switch between them). Finding those will help track the actual problem down.

Also, since you mentioned changing package names you may want to check my answer here: [Serializing CDT Project settings has encountered a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521467/serializing-cdt-project-settings-has-encountered-a/28873491#28873491). I'm fairly certain that changing the package name for my project was what caused Eclipse to corrupt my project configuration back then.